# Magento 2 - Street Address in OSC is not being saved

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Got a weird issue. My site is running Magento 2.3, everything was working fine a week ago. Decided to do one last check before launch and now have a weird situation where the Street Address is not being saved.

[image]

I changed it from 2 lines to 1 but it does not work.

It also caused the checkout form to NOT validate and gives me the following error -

> Please check the shipping address information. "street" is required. Enter and try again.

Comment: "I changed it from 2 lines to 1 but it does not work" -> How?

Comment: Originally in Stores > Configuration  > Customers > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options, I had the number of lines in street address as 2, I changed to 1, but the error persists. Not sure what else I can try

Comment: That's fine. Maybe a bug or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options, then change a field > Save, then change that field back to the original setting > Save again seems to reset it.